# How to disable bounce in horizontal Flatlist on iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have tried to disable bounce from Flatlist properties using bounces={false}, bouncesZoom={false}, alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}. But it's still bouncing.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NbfR.jpg)

```js
<FlatList
  data={dataBackgroundMap}
  pagingEnabled={false}
  bounces={false}
  alwaysBounceHorizontal={false}
  bouncesZoom={false}
  keyExtractor={(item: any) => item.id}
  renderItem={({item, index}: any) => {
    return (
      <>
        <FastImage
          {...addTestID(item.id)}
          key={item.id}
          style={{
            width: widthScreen * 1.4,
            height: heightScreen - 120,
          }}
          resizeMode="stretch"
          source={item.imageUrl}
        />
      </>
    );
  }}
  horizontal
/>
```

Comment: Why is your image width more than screen width?